# How can I determine the test coverage within my own project for a given dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I have a large codebase with many dependencies, with a variable amount of test coverage across the project. When I upgrade a dependency, I want to know how much test coverage that dependency has within my own project. To phrase it another way, for all of the instances where a specific dependency is called, how many of those instances are covered by one of my tests? Is there a way to determine that with a tool like JaCoCo?

Comment: for the dependency? no you can not. no one publishes tests and results of those as artifacts (very , _very_ rarely that might happen)

Comment: I would think that if they are open source you might go to the site to research such information.

Comment: Sorry, when I say how much test coverage that dependency has, I'm referring to within my own project, not within the dependency's tests. i.e. how many instances where that dependency is called is covered with one of my own tests?

I've edited my question to clarify this